# Splitting SpaCy Docs into sentences in custom pipeline component

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, spacy-3, spacy-transformers

I am building a SpaCy pipeline and would like to split sentences into individual `Doc` objects. According to the [SpaCy documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components), custom pipeline components take a single `Doc` object as input and return a single `Doc` object. However, I would like to input paragraphs/sections of text and have the SpaCy pipeline pass each `Doc`'s sentences to the next component of the pipeline as its own `Doc`. This does not seem to be possible and I was hoping to find a workaround.

We would like to do this because we have trained a `textcat` component that classifies sentences that are relevant to our use case. However, without splitting the sentences before the `textcat` component, we only get predictions on the entire `Doc` object.

In essence, I would like to do the following, but wrapped up into a SpaCy `@Language.component`:

```
relevant_sents = []
for sent in doc.sents:
    cats = textcat_model(sent).cats
    if cats.get("RELEVANT") > 0.5:
        relevant_sents.append(sent)
```

However, to achieve this, I need some sort of work around to feed individual sentences into the `textcat` component of the pipeline as `Doc` objects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components have to return the same number of Docs that they take in, that can't be changed.

What you should do in this situation is have two pipelines / `nlp` objects. Use the sentences on the first one to create Docs that you pass to the second one.

In the past pipelines only took text as input, but recently it's become possible to pass Docs as well. When passing a Doc, tokenization is skipped but other components are run.

Comment: Thanks so much for responding! That's what I thought too and I'm a bit disappointed. We were hoping to host our model publicly and have all of the preprocessing built into the model itself, but your response confirms that we will need to release two separate models. 

We'll try having the second model take the Docs as inputs, that's a great idea. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: If my comment was helpful, in addition to upvoting you can "accept" it by clicking the big checkmark to the left of it.